# install adobe reader with windows powershell

Tags: powershell, scripting, windows-server-2008-r2

I work with a lot of servers and want to configure a powershell script to install adobe reader. It seems like once I have format for a script for this I can then install other programs i need like (netmon) and (sqlxml 4.0).

These .exe files would be stored on D:\

Thanks for you help

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to download full version of Adobe Reader installer (not the web installer), but offline installer that is around 40 mb. Then run this script:

```
&"C:\AdbeRdr1000_en_US.exe" /msi EULA_ACCEPT=YES /qn
```

The only difficulty is that it's asynchronous, so it doesn't wait for installation to complete before exiting

As for any application, just google for command line options and run it from PowerShell